# How can I access VS Code server from multiple accounts?

Tags: linux, github, visual-studio-code, text-editor, multiple-accounts

I need to use VS Code Server to resolve programming issues in a project, but VS does not allow me to use multiple accounts to access VS Code Server on my Linux server, only one GitHub account. I'm looking for a way to use VS Code Server as an online editor to solve programming questions and send these codes to a web application. In short, I need to use the VS code server on a Linux server, as a code editor for several students to solve programming questions and return an answer to the platform. How can I do this?

I tried using VS code on the local network to try to use multiple accounts, I also tried a Linux server, but reading the documentation I realized that there was a usage limitation for just one account associated with GitHub. Now I'm researching how it works using containers, and I'm also going to research whether there's a way to implement the VS code editor in my web application.